# How to transform classify_image_graph_def.pb from "TF for poets" tutorial into inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb from Qualcomm SNPE tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, graph, qualcomm, snpe

Does anybody know, how to transform ***classify_image_graph_def.pb*** from google's tensorflow for poets tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

into
 ***inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb*** utilised by Qualcomm in its SNPE SNPE tutorial:
https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/tutorial_setup.html
?

When I retrain the ***classify_image_graph_def.pb***, freeze it and use it as a model in the Qualcomm SNPE tutorial, then the app compiles OK but stops running on my Android device. (runtime error)

Comment: Just edited the question to make it simpler and easy to understand. Release from hold, please